# How to create separate usr partition during arch install?

Tags: arch-linux, mount, partition, lvm, luks

How do I modify and add the hooks needed in mkinitcpio to have a separate usr partition?
Also, am I mounting the other partitions correctly?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zp34J.jpg

Basically I'm using UEFI with GPT, I'm planning on using grub, but may change to gummiboot. I have LVM on LUKS. I want separate root, home, var, opt, tmp, and usr partitions.

Did I mount the other partitions correctly? And how do I configure mkinitcpio to allow this? I can modify the fstab manually if need be.

Comment: Any reason why you want /usr to be separate? Nobody does that anymore.